# ActiveRecord polymorpic model association confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations, rails-migrations, model-associations

I have a rails 4 application whereby I've set up a User model. I want the User to have a *has_many* association with a user profile model, but here's the catch:

1. My user profile model needs to be [polymorphic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) - the
   User model can have multiple (different) user profiles associated
   with it (e.g. ProfileTypeA, ProfileTypeB, ProfileTypeC, etc.)
2. I want my User model to have one association, say, user_profiles, that
   would return the all the user's user profiles associated with it.

I believe I'm on the right track (or am I?), but how would this be accomplished using the rails generator? The part that is most confusing to me, is how to do bullet #2 above.

P.S. I took a look at [STI](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)'s, but it seems to me that my User model would have to have a hard-association with each user profile type model, which I don't like because it would change the User model with each new user profile type I add to the data model.

Answer (score 1):

You sound on right track,try below

```
#The polymorphic models
class User
  has_many :user_profiles, as: :profileable
end

class UserProfile
 belongs_to :profileable, polymorphic: true
end
```

The Migrations below

```
#migrations
class CreateUserProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_profiles do |t|
      t.integer :profileable_id
      t.string  :profileable_type
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :user_profiles, :profileable_id
  end
end
```

Comment: AnkitG - That seems to be what I'm looking for, but assuming I have 

class UserAProfile < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_many :user_profiles, as: :profileable 
end

How would I add an UserAProfile object to User#user_profiles?

This is my UserAProfile migration:

create_table "user_a_profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
   # will add more fields later...
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end